# Is the proposition $[KL:L]=[K:F]$ iff $K\cap L=F$ for finite Galois extension still hold for separable extension?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, separable-extension

I know that when $K/F$ and $L/F$ are finite Galois extension (where $L, K<\overline{F}$), $[KL:L]$ divides $[K:F]$, and $[KL:L]=[K:F]$ iff $K\cap L=F$.

My question is that above proposition is still valid for finite separable extension $K/F$ and $L/F$. I couldn't find counterexample...

Comment: Note that $[KL:L]=[K:F]$ if and only if $[KL:F]=[K:F]\cdot [L:F]$. Can you at least prove that, in general, $[KL:F]\le [K:F]\cdot [L:F]$ by playing around with bases for $K$ and $L$ over $F$? Now what if we construct our bases by extending a basis of $K\cap L$ in two ways? What kind of inequality do you get then?

Comment: Now that WhatsUp has given a counterexample, note that my comment would have given you the one implication which is true. Namely, $[KL:L] \le [K:F]-\frac{[K\cap L:F]}{[L:F]}$, so if $K\cap L\neq F$, then $[KL:L]\neq [K:F]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $F = \Bbb Q$, $L = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ (embedded in $\Bbb R$) and $K = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2\omega)$ where $\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}$ is a primitive root of unity.

Then $KL = \Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2, \omega)$ has degree $6$ over $\Bbb Q$ and hence $[KL : L] = 2 < [K:F]$. However it is clear that $K \cap L = F$.

---

To explain a bit the general situation, I have answered [a MathOverFlow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280081/tensor-product-of-field-extensions/280090#280090) on the tensor product of two fields (of characteristic zero) in which I explained that $K \otimes_F L$ is isomorphic to the direct product of all compositums of $K$ and $L$ over $F$.

Since $K \otimes_F L$ has dimension $[K:F][L:F]$ over $F$, it is clear that we have $[KL:L] = [K:F]$ iff $KL$ is the only compositum of $K$ and $L$ over $F$. This usually is not the case for non-Galois extensions.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a counterexaple for another direction? That is, [KL:L]=[K:F] but K∩L is not F

Comment: No, this is not possible because we always have $[KL:F] \leq [K:F][L:F]$ since $KL$ is a direct factor of $K\otimes_F L$. If we write $F' = K\cap L$, then this inequality applied to the extensions $K/F'$ and $L/F'$ gives $[KL:F'] \leq [K:F'][L:F']$, i.e. $[KL:F][F':F] \leq [K:F][L:F]$. Therefore $[KL:L] = [K:F]$ would imply that $[F':F] \leq 1$ and hence $F' = F$.